# How do I build a logo image from hundreds of small slices on a webpage

Tags: jquery, image, photoshop, slice

I would like to slice up a logo image and build it on a webpage from lots of small slices and I am wondering what the best way to do this would be.  I would rather avoid flash if possible.

I can slice up the logo in Photoshop and gradually remove the slices, and save it as a series of images which run as a slideshow.  But as I am talking about a lot of slices, say around 500, that would take time and may not look as good as other methods.

Is there a way, using jQuery perhaps, of building an image from lots of small html elements?

Or perhaps there is a better way still?

I'd be glad of any advice.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea that I think would be fairly easy even with "plain" JavaScript (but much easier with jQuery):

1. Include the full image on your page with a style of `visibility : hidden`, inside a container div of the same size.
2. Use jQuery to create a grid of little opaque divs absolutely positioned inside the same container div, with a `z-index` that places them above the image, i.e., covering the image. As you create them store a reference to each in an array.
3. Set the image to `visibility : "visible"`
4. Randomly sort the aforementioned array and then loop through it with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, removing a div on each iteration to gradually reveal the picture.

Of course the advantage of the above is that it would work with any picture without having to slice it up, and given that you mentioned 500 slices you wouldn't have 500 http requests to load all the pieces of picture. If you wanted each individual slice reveal to have a little animation effect you could hide it with jQuery's `.slideUp()` or something.

On the other hand, you may like each piece of the picture to come flying in from different directions or something. For that you could still create the grid of divs, but set each to have a (CSS) background of your image with appropriate offset values so that each makes a separate piece of the "puzzle".

EDIT: I forgot to mention that there's probably already a jQuery plugin (if not numerous plugins) that do this sort of thing. I'm not aware of a specific one, but you may like to do some googling. The above is just the first thing that came to mind as a way to code it from scratch...

**EDIT 2: Working (sort of) demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/sEE8R/1/ (This is just some dodgy code that I cobbled together loosely based on the algorithm above. Instead of an image I've used a red div, which gets covered in green divs that are randomly removed.)

Comment: I think this would work well, although I would fear that performance could be an issue.

Comment: @NateB - I cobbled together a very rough demo as per my edit above. The performance problem is in the animation of the reveal: removing one block at a time via `setInterval` takes quite a while with 400 pieces in a 20x20 grid, though removing 2 - 4 pieces per interval speeds it up to what I'd say is an acceptable level.

Answer (score 1):

Use the original image as though it were a [CSS sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS), and programmatically create elements that are subset slices of it.

Alternatively, load your image, repeatedly use `drawImage()` to draw subsections of it to an HTML5 Canvas, use `toDataURL()` to get a string and create `new Image` in JS set to this data URL.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check:

http://slicephotoshop.com

to easily "slice" your logo, if your logo is made out of layers.